# Using USB stick to save and access steam games

Tags: usb, steam

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and I have just installed it like 10 minutes ago to replace Chrome OS. I do not know any commands currently or how to explore any Linux system to be exact. My question is; is it possible to use a USB drive for steam games and if so, how? When I try to download them onto the 16gb exsisting ssd I get the out of space message. When I try to save it on the usb I get a message saying something about the drive not having excute permission. Can I turn the FlashDrive into a harddrive?

Comment: It is nearly identicle but I am using an 32gb flashdrive that gives me the message "doesnt have execute permissions" I understand how to save in the location, I just dont know how to give my flashdrive executeable permissions

Comment: Try formatting the USB drive in ext4 format. Then you should be able to set the execute permission.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you could turn a flash drive into a hard drive :P

But however you could use a usb for steam games (I think), all you have to do is create a soft link. Run this command replacing {YOUR_USERNAME} with your username and {YOUR_USB_PATH} with where your usb is mounted:

`ln -s {YOUR_USB_PATH}/Steam /home/{YOUR_USERNAME}/.local/share/Steam`

WARNING: This command is not tested, use at your own risk...

NOTE: How to find where your usb is mounted:

1. Click on your USB in the sidebar.
2. In the new window that opens, press `CTRL+L`
3. The text at the top is where your usb is mounted, copy it and replace {YOUR_USB_PATH} in the command with it...

Comment: Where do I enter this command? @user2898813 is it in the terminal and do I have to add sudo?

Comment: Just in the terminal, no sudo should be needed. After this just save Steam games where they would normally be saved (NOT ON THE USB) it will look like they are on the computer but they are actually on the USB.

Comment: I got this message: "bash: in: command not found"

Comment: Am I using the wrong thing to enter the command?

Comment: xterminal or uxterminal?

Comment: Any of them: It's not an I at the start, it's an "L" (lowercase) watch out for these tiny details...

Comment: My bad LOL! I always get them mixed haha

Comment: By the way, there is another solution here on Steam if this one doesn't work: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/666827316152433246/

Comment: "Permission Denied" What I got after entering the code @user2898813

Comment: Can you tell me what you are typing?

Comment: ln -s {/media/removable/D}/steam /home/{thgaming}/.local/share/Steam @user2898813

Comment: whoops, sorry, you can remove the {}s

Comment: I entered the code, hit enter, took me back to the normal "(precise)thgaming@localhost:~$" So I opened Steam, tryed using the original save location and it still said not enough space. Does this mean it does not work or am I still messing up? @user2898813

Comment: Then I have no idea, Steam must not support soft links, just follow the solution here instead, it's even more difficult to follow though but you can take a shot:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/666827316152433246/

Comment: Will look into it! Don't know if this will change anything but the full message I get is "New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with excute permissions" @user2898813